# Issue with connecting to URL

Tags: java, network-programming, http-headers

This is how request is supposed to look(at the top) : [image]

And this is my code in Java :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL("http://ishin-global.aktsk.com");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("/ping ", " HTTP/1.1");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host"," ishin-global.aktsk.com");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept"," */*");
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-Platform"," android");
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-ClientVersion"," 3.1.2");
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-Language"," en");
    conn.connect();

    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

The issue is that i don't get response from the server,but i get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ishin-global.aktsk.com
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1836)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

I haven't been able to figure it out,so i asked here.Thanks in advance

Comment: In your image, the URL begins with `https`, not `http`.

Comment: did you check the response code/message? i.e. `conn.getResponseMessage()`

Comment: I changed `http` to `https` and it's still the same,i get code 404 when using `conn.getResponseMessage()` but url is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conn.setRequestProperty("/ping ", " HTTP/1.1");` is incorrect.  `/ping` is not an HTTP request header, it’s the path of the URL.  A URL’s path is part of the URL itself, not a header:

```
URL url = new URL("http://ishin-global.aktsk.com/ping");
```

Remove the `conn.setRequestProperty("/ping ", " HTTP/1.1");` line.  Java (and every HTTP client) will automatically send the correct initial line when they connect.